# Python Extend range of excel table conditional formats

Tags: python, excel, conditional-formatting

I use python to read an existed excel file and append a table it contains.
This work fine.

My issue is that, despite I imaged to extend the range of the table and add the extra row, I cannot extend the existed conditional formats of the sheet.

Can maybe someone help me?

In [How to update range of cells where Excel Conditional Formatting applies with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300543/how-to-update-range-of-cells-where-excel-conditional-formatting-applies-with-ope) post I have found this code in which makes sense:

```
import re
from os import startfile

from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook(xlsx)
ws = wb["My Super Worksheet"]

range_cells = "A4:V4"
new_range = "A4:V100"

rules = ws.conditional_formatting[range_cells]
del ws.conditional_formatting[range_cells]
for rule in rules:
    ws.conditional_formatting.add(new_range, rule)

wb.save()
```

However, when I run the line:

```
rules = ws.conditional_formatting[range_cells]
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.